# ha_sequence plugin usage in MySQL

Tags: mysql, plugins, mariadb

Is there any possibility to use the **ha_sequence** plugin provided by **MariaDB** in **MySQL** (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-storage-engine/)? Or does a similar plugin exist for MySQL? I want to list a sequence between two numbers but in one simple line without procedures,  functions or tables. Currently I use this query or workaround for my sequence, which is a variation I found [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75785/how-to-generate-a-sequence-in-mysql):

```
select (h*100+t*10+u+1) x from 
   (select 0 h union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
   select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) A, 
   (select 0 t union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union
   select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) B, 
   (select 0 u union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union 
   select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) C
where (h*100+t*10+u+1) between 1 and 366
order by x;
```

I am using MySQL Community Server 5.7.23 on Debian 9. I already have tried to copy the plugin file from MariaDB to my MySQL server and install it but without success. I guess it is not compatible with MySQL since it is a plugin for MariaDB. Here is the command I have tried:

```
mysql> install plugin sequence soname 'ha_sequence.so';
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library '/usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_sequence.so' (errno: 2 /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_sequence.so: undefined symbol: _ZN7handler11print_errorEim)
```

**Edit (2018-09-17):**

Before I’ve accepted the answer I also tried to compile the plugin source code for MySQL. I was semi successful because I have managed to compile it with some modifications. However, the plugin needs some features (functions) from classes in MySQL which are not present in the MySQL source. So it did not work. Adding these features or implementing a workaround directly into the plugin, or modifying the MySQL source to my needs, would have cost me to much time. I really did not want to dig to much into the source codes of MySQL and/or MariaDB. So I gave up and now I work with the above described query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the MariaDB plugins only work with MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

One-time, build yourself a million-row table with just numbers (and a `PRIMARY KEY`).

Henceforth, `JOIN` to that table to get the numbers (and limit it with `BETWEEN` or whatever).